# How to display with MathJax using AsciiMath?

Tags: javascript, html, mathjax, asciimath

I'm using **MathJax** to display math formulas in my website. And now, I want to use **AsciiMath** too. The problem is, when I'm using **AsciiMath** delimiters `` `...` `` instead of **MathJax** delimiters `$...$` it doesn't work.

**This is my JS code** (works on r.e. with MathJax delimiters):

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
 MathJax.Hub.Config({
  tex2jax: {
   inlineMath: [["$","$"],["\\(","\\)"]],
   displayMath: [['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"]]
  },
  asciimath2jax: {
   delimiters: [['\\$','\\$'], ['`','`']]
  }
 });
</script>
```

So, if I write in my **HTML** `<p>$x^2$</p>` it displays: [Click to view img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paX9z.png).

But, if I write `` <p>`x^2`</p> `` the display is: [Click to view img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzStp.png).

Also, I'm using this **CDN** in the bottom of my **HTML** code:

```
<script src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML-full"></script>
```

**NOTE** that if I put it in the top of my **HTML** code, doesn't work either.

Comment: Try the documentation at https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/asciimath.html.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger already did, not working..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are loading a configuration file that only includes the TeX input processor, not the AsciiMath one.  The only combined configuration files that load both TeX and AsciiMath also load the MathML input processor, so if you are OK With that, then you could use

```
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@2/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML-full"></script>
```

(I've changed your call from the decommissioned MathJax CDN to an active one.)

If you only want TeX and AsciiMath, then you have to load one fo them using the `MathJax.Hub.Config()` call, as in

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
 MathJax.Hub.Config({
  jax: ['input/AsciiMath'],
  extensions: ['asciimath2jax.js'],
  tex2jax: {
   inlineMath: [["$","$"],["\\(","\\)"]],
   displayMath: [['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"]]
  },
  asciimath2jax: {
   delimiters: [['\\$','\\$'], ['`','`']]
  }
 });
</script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@2/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_CHTML-full"></script>
```